# strEnglishPhrase is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])?

Tags: java, string

I cant seem to get this to work, this is my first java class so any help is much appreciated:
heres what i have so far:

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pig extends Object{

    public static void main( String[] args){
         Console console = System.console();
        String strEnglishPhrase;
        char choice;
        do{
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!!");
            strEnglishPhrase =
                console.readLine("Enter Phrase for Translation : ");
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

             String strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();

            if(strEnglishPhrase != null && !strEnglishPhrase.equals("")){
                System.out.println("Phrase in Pig Latin : \n"
                    + convertEnglishToPigLatin(strEnglishPhrase));
            } else{
                System.out.println("Whoops, Invalid Entry.");
            }
            choice =
                console
                    .readLine("Do you want to continue? y" + '/' + "n?")
                    .charAt(0);
        } while((choice != 'n') && (choice != 'N'));
    }

    public static String convertEnglishToPigLatin( String strEnglishPhrase){
         String strVowels = "aeiou";
         String[] strTokens = strEnglishPhrase.split("[ ]");
         StringBuffer sbPigLatinStuff = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < strTokens.length; i++){
            if(strVowels.indexOf(strTokens[i].charAt(0)) >= 0){
                sbPigLatinStuff.append(strTokens[i] + "way ");
            } else if((strTokens[i].indexOf("a") < 0)
                && (strTokens[i].indexOf("e") < 0)
                && (strTokens[i].indexOf("i") < 0)
                && (strTokens[i].indexOf("o") < 0)
                && (strTokens[i].indexOf("u") < 0)){
                sbPigLatinStuff.append(strTokens[i] + "ay ");
            } else{
                for(int j = 1; j < strTokens[i].length(); j++){
                    if(strVowels.indexOf(strTokens[i].charAt(j)) >= 0){
                        sbPigLatinStuff.append(strTokens[i].substring(j)
                            + strTokens[i].substring(0, j) + "ay ");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return sbPigLatinStuff.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use an IDE (like Eclipse). It will immediately show you what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You have a double declaration of the string variable strEnglishPhrase within the same scope.

```
public class Pig extends Object
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)     
    { 
        Console console = System.console();

        // First declaration of strEnglishPhrase!
        String strEnglishPhrase; 

        char choice; 

        do { 
           System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!!"); 
           strEnglishPhrase = console.readLine("Enter Phrase for Translation : ");
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

           // Second and duplicate declaration of strEnglishPhrase!

           String strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();  

           ...
        }
     ...
    }
 }
```

You can solve the problem by removing the type declaration of **strEnglishPhrase** in your do-loop:

```
 // Replace this line
 String strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();  

 // by this line:
 strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

My Java isn't brilliant but you seem to have declared `strEnglishPhrase` at the start of your `main` method and then again your `while` loop.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)     
{ 
Console console = System.console();
String strEnglishPhrase;  <<-- declared here
char choice;
do
{
 System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!!");
 strEnglishPhrase = console.readLine("Enter Phrase for Translation : ");  
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  

   String strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine(); <<-- And again here
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that at the top of your code, you have

```
Console console = System.console();
String strEnglishPhrase;
char choice;
```

Which defines a `String` called `strEnglishPhrase`.  However, in the body of the loop, you also write

```
String strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();
```

This tries to define a new variable also called `strEnglishPhrase`, which conflicts with the earlier definition.

To fix this, either remove the declaration from outside the loop, or change the above code to read

```
strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();
```

which is an assignment rather than a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You declared strEnglishPhrase for the first time here:

```
Console console = System.console();
String strEnglishPhrase;
char choice;
```

and then you define it again at this point:

```
String strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();
```

Just remove at this point the 'String' keyword.

```
strEnglishPhrase = scanner.nextLine();
```